# Pointer Aithmetic

Tags: c++, math, pointers

Trying to understand Pointer Arithmetic when dealing with arrays. It seems to me they're used for fast access of arrays, but maybe I'm totally wrong. I mean if we have this:

*(myArray + 1), we're going to the next location in the array I think.

I'm converting some C++ to C# and the C++ has pointer arithmetic going on. I need the C# to be totally managed so trying to figure out how to translate the pointer stuff to C#.

THanks for any ideas.

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not completely comfortable with pointers, your life will be a bit easier in C#.  First off, the code you posted:

```
`*(myArray + 1)`
```

Your understanding is basically correct, you are dereferencing the 1st element in `myArray`.  Or in other words, accessing `myArray[1]`.

Moving to C#, you likely use a generic `List<T>` where `T` is the type of your `myArray`.  Similar syntax is available to you - `myArray[i]`, plus many more functions on the `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If myArray[1] is preferred, and I know pointer arithmetic is useful in some way, is it really useful then in the context of arrays?

Comment: @DavidWhitten - Everyone has an opinion on that one. Check out [this SO discussion on pointer arithmetic vs indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/693139/704402) for some ideas. At the end of the day, gravitate towards readable code. A heaping mess of pointer arithmetic may indeed look awesome, but you're not doing the next guy any favors.  Especially if that next guy is you.

Answer (score 2):

`*(myArray + 1)` is exactly equivalent to `myArray[1]`. You should always prefer the latter. It is easier to read and there will be no difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

And *(myArray +1) equals myArray[1].

Comment: That site's description of the relationship between pointers and arrays is woefully inaccurate.  It gets the code right, but the description of arrays as *"constant pointers"* is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `myArray` points to the beginning of an array (any by its name, it should), `*(myArray + 1)` is the same thing as `myArray[1]`, and the latter is preferred for readability.

The trickier part of converting pointer arithmetic code is when you are using a pointer to some random part of the array - `*(current + 1)` where `current` is a pointer to an arbitrary element in an array.  Here, you have to figure out the original array and the index within the array of the element that `current` points to.  Assuming that it is `myArray` and `i`, the above code translates to `myArray[i+1]`