# Why local variable pointer?

Tags: c

In this piece of code (extracted from qemacs' source code)

```
static int goto_char(u8 *buf, int pos, QECharset *charset)
{
    int nb_chars, c;
    u8 *buf_ptr;

    if (charset != &charset_utf8)
        return pos;

    nb_chars = 0;
    buf_ptr = buf;
    for(;;) {
        c = *buf_ptr;
        if (c < 0x80 || c >= 0xc0) {
            if (nb_chars >= pos)
                break;
            nb_chars++;
        }
        buf_ptr++;
    }
    return buf_ptr - buf;
}
```

why not access buf directly instead of making a local variable pointer?

Comment: How would they do `buf_ptr++;` and `return buf_ptr - buf;` in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you increment `buf`, you would loose track of original `buf` address and thus the length.

There are 2 solutions to this: Either keep a copy of original variable, use another temp walking pointer to increment buf pointer or keep an index counter.

This implementation used the second. Moreover there are many programmers who refrain from changing function arguments to avoid any surprises.

Although you can avoid `buf_ptr` and use `buf[some_index++]`, but some ancient compilers could generate faster code when `walking pointers` were used instead of indices.

Related: [What are convincing examples where pointer arithmetic is preferable to array subscripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693139/what-are-convincing-examples-where-pointer-arithmetic-is-preferable-to-array-sub)

Comment: I feel happy if the answer helped.